# highlight region when uploading file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "panel-body" where I can drop a csv file and fill some fields.

ejs file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="fileUpload">click to upload file</div> 
 </div>
```

js file:

```
function theUploader() {
  $('#fileUpload').fileReaderJS({
    dragClass: 'drag',
    readAsDefault: 'Text',
    on: {
      load: theUpload
    }
  });
}
```

Now , I want to be able not only to drag a file but to click on the `click to upload file` field and open the local directory.

So , I tried:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-sm fileinput-button">
            <span>click to upload file</span> 
                <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/upload" multiple>     
            </span>
</div>
```

Now, I am able to drag or open the local directory , but :

1) The region where `click to upload file` is , isn't highlighted anymore when draging the file into it.

2) The above region is smaller in width than before ( probably because now using the fileinput button span and it created a border around the words `click to upload file` which didn't exist in the initial setup which used only the drag option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just hide `<input type="file">` and on drop region click trigger click for that hidden input.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" />

<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="fileUpload">click to upload file</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=file] {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#fileUpload').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});
```

Full test here https://jsfiddle.net/4n73ksxs/

**Edit**

Here is full demo of FileReader.js with changed code like you need it https://jsfiddle.net/ju5h1n6t/

You can see that only this code is added at the bottom:

```
  $('input[type=file]').hide();
  $('#dropzone').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
  });
```

Comment: :Is there a way without the css file?Without changing the type=file?(Also,i am not sure if the highlight will work).And I want both drag and local folder to open.

Comment: You could do `$('input[type=file]').hide();` or add some id/class to it and target that. Highlight will work I tested it with FileReader.js. You use that right?

Comment: :I would prefer if you can 'step' onto my existing code and make the necessary changes.Probably playing with the html or the fileReaderJS I already have.Because like this I have to change a few things in order to try if your code works for me.If you can , ok I will try it and let you know.Thank you for the help.

Comment: :I tried your implementation and unfortunately it doesn't work.Neither the click nor the drag..Also , I am doing `<div id="fileUpload" type="file">click to upload file</div>` because if I put the `<input type="file">` as you had it,it creates another small empty frame.

Comment: :Unfortunately I can't share the code..Let alone that it is big also.Is there any way to accomplish this using my code in question?Because it is fully functional except these 2 problems.Anyway , thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't try with your approach because I think it is more complicated and more code needs to be edited or added. I updated my answer with exact demo from FileReader.js and you can see that only few lines are added for this to work.

Comment: :The problem is that in a previous step I want to use the `type=file` and I don't know how to override this.I tried but with no success.If you have an idea about this. ( upvoting for your help )

Comment: :It's a lot of code.. :) And I am not sure where to look.In a few words,I want to use in a previous step `type=file` and at the next step the drag/click (which I tried to give it a name , `type=newname`) and do all the things in your answer but it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114056/discussion-between-jakob-and-george).